# How to sort on one of the composite keys in Hibernate using @OrderBy

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting, sql-order-by, composite-key

I have two classes `Course` and `Student`. `Student` class use `firstName` and `lastName` as the composite-key. I want to use `@OrderBy("firstName ASC")`  in `Course` class, but there is an error *"property from @OrderBy clause not found: Student.firstName"*.

**How can I sort on one of the composite keys (such as `firstName`)?**

```
public class Course{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="course")
    @OrderBy("firstName ASC")  
    // Error: property from @OrderBy clause not found: Student.firstName, why?
    private List<Student> students;
.....
}


public class Student{
    @Id
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firtName;
    @Id
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="course_id")
    private Course course;
.....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled it to, `firtName` -- notice `s` is missing. Fix that and things will be fine, most likely.

**[Edited]**

In case it is still not working. Try to replace this by `@EmbeddedId`, instead. Like below,

```
public class Student implements Serializable{
    @EmbeddedId
    private StudentPK name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="course_id")
    private Course course;
    .....

    @Embeddable
    public static class StudentPK implements Serializable {
        @Column(name="first_name")
        private String firtName;

        @Column(name="last_name")
        private String lastName;

        ....
    }
}
```

Then it should work using,

```
public class Course{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="course")
    @OrderBy("name.firstName ASC")  
    private List students;
    .....
}
```

Comment: it's not caused by the misspelling, i corrected it, but still get the error. seems hibernate implemented the composite key as one field internal, and firstName is not a valid field for Student any more. if this is true, is there any way to order by firstName?

Comment: the default is order by primary key {firstName, lastName}, but I only need to order by firstName.

Comment: @hebingliu: Updated my post, accordingly.